# How can I control external USB light?

Tags: android, usb

For a hospital management software I need to control an external USB light. Suppose, a android device is in a Doctor room which always connected with a USB light & server. When a patient need an emergency support then server sent info on that device & device turn on it's USB Light with emergency sound. Now, I am suffering to control the USB light. If you don't have any clear solution then you can suggest me a way in which way can I go to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: A good question should describe the problem and the steps you have taken to solve it.  Have you picked out a particular USB light?  Can you link to its product page?  Have you written any code for Android whatsoever?  What problems are you having with the code?  Do you need help finding a USB library to use on Android?  Also, since it sounds like this is application critical to the safety of the patient, I think a lot of people would be hesitant to help.  This project should probably be done by someone who knows more about what they are doing.

Comment: Its a part of this project... After a lot of googling I don't find any perfect library that works. And any light would be... Suppose : http://en.miui.com/thread-49148-1-1.html
And we don't find any efficient people how already have this kind of experience...

Answer (score 0):

Is it a special USB light? If not you could use or modify the [MailNotifier Usb Light from Dream Cheeky](http://dreamcheeky.com/webmail-notifier) for 10-20€ (can display all colors) and my wrapper class I just [blogged about](http://codingyourlife.at/?page_id=1102) that uses a HidLibrary. There is also a [Linux driver](http://codingyourlife.at/?page_id=1095) that's quite easy to install and runs on a Raspberry Pi too.

If you take my advice and use a RaspberryPi and want to tell the device remotely what color to pick the easiest way with C# might be the SSH.NET nuget package. But that could be difficult to put on mobile devices. A different approach is to create a webserver on the RaspberryPi with a tiny PHP API. Another advantage of the RaspberryPi is that it has an audio jacket where you can attach external speakers for the emergency sound.

If you have any questions feel free to comment. Sorry that my blog-links are in German. At least the WrapperClass itself is written in English.